# PHP Display Alternating Records from Table

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

Ok, so, you guys were extremely helpful with my last issue, so , why not try again?

I have a page where I'm trying to display records from a table in an alternating style (left vs right aligned).  While I know the importance of prepared statements and such, I just need to see that it works correctly before I clean up the code (call it my OCD).

I'm having issues getting any records to display.  Essentially, I'm running a `foreach` loop inside a scrollable `div` in hopes that it takes each record and displays them appropriately.

Thoughts?

```
<div style="height:450px; overflow:auto;">
<?php 
//$gID = sprintf("%d", $_GET['gearID']);
$query = "SELECT * FROM GearTable";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

/*trick the items into aligning left or right in alternating pattern*/
$x++; 
$align = ($x%2 == 0)? 'left': 'right';

//if rows exist
if ($num_rows > 0)
{
    foreach ($result as $row)
    {
        echo "
                <div style='margin-top:8px;'>
                    <img src='{$row['GearImgLoc']}' width='200' align='left' class='imgGear'>
                    <h2>{$row['GearName']}</h2>
                    <p class='textP'><b>Gear Manufacturer:</b> {$row['GearMFG']}</p>
                    <p class='textP'><b>Gear Description:</b> {$row['GearDesc']}</p>
                    <p><span class='posted'>Date Posted: {$row['DatePosted']} | Posted By: {$row['PostedBy']}</span></p>
                    <p><a href='gear.php?type=edit&id={$row['GearID']}'>Edit</a> | <a href='gear.php?type=delete&id={$row['GearID']}'>Discard</a> |  <a href='preview.php?gearID={$row['GearID']}'>Preview</a></p>
                </div>
            ";  
    }
}
else
{
    echo "No Records Available At This Time";
}
?>
</div>
```

Comment: Surely you want `$x++; 
$align = ($x%2 == 0)? 'left': 'right';` inside your `foreach` loop?

Comment: I guess that would make sense.

Comment: you need to use Mysql_fetch_array or other command to fetch the result so try instead of foreach ($result as $row) to use while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `mysql_result()` to use the result object.

For example:

```
$query = "SELECT Name, CountryCode FROM City ORDER by ID LIMIT 3";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

/* numeric array */
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_NUM);
```

Taken from the PHP documentation.

For more information: http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php

**Just for the sake of the question:**

This is how it works using MySQL (which is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0 therefore I suggest you to move to MySQLi or PDO as soon as possible):

```
mysql_connect("localhost", "mysql_user", "mysql_password") or
    die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("mydb");

$result = mysql_query("SELECT id, name FROM mytable");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) {
    printf("ID: %s  Name: %s", $row[0], $row[1]);  
}

mysql_free_result($result);
```

Comment: He's using mysql not mysqli statement.

Comment: Nothing changes, they still are the same functions pretty much, without mentioning that MySQL is deprecated @Goikiu.

Comment: Is it deprecated however he needs to change other thing before using your code ;) You can explain WHY, it will be helpful for him.

Comment: Don't know why this is getting voted down... it's the correct answer, albeit with a different library.

Comment: @JohnChrysostom I've voted it down because he need to Explain WHY changing from mysql to mysqli and how he can do it for a complete answer.

Comment: After the edit He gained a +1 from me. A good answer explains everything (i think so).

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should put you in the right direction:

```
foreach ($result as $i => $row) {

     $class_name = ( $i % 2 == 0 ? 'left' : 'right' );
```